# The image is Frozen despite calling for methods to update it

Tags: scala, awt

I'm trying to write code to display black circles moving around in a window using AWT and scala. I successfully drew  circles where I want them but the image is frozen.

I am using a simple game-loop inside a run() method in a Display class extending Frame :

```
final class Display(
    val canvas: Canvas, 
    val updater : Updater
) extends Frame  with Runnable {

  this.add(canvas)

  override def run() ={

    setSize(canvas.size())
    setVisible(true)

    var updateTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    while(true) {
      val frameStart = System.currentTimeMillis()
      val frameEnd = frameStart + MILLIS_PER_FRAME
      repaint()
      canvas.paint(getGraphics())

      while(updateTime < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        updater.update(MILLIS_PER_UPDATE, keyboard)
        updateTime += MILLIS_PER_UPDATE
      }

      while(System.currentTimeMillis() < frameEnd) Thread.sleep(1)
    }

    setVisible(false)
  }
```

I called

```
repaint()
canvas.paint(getGraphics())
```

Thinking that it would call draw the image on the Frame again according to the paint() method of *canvas*. But apparently that's not how it works...

I trust the *paint(g : Graphics)* method of my canvas is working properly, and I verified with println()-debugging that the circles should be moving.

Please ask for any bit of code that could help you answering, and thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`repaint()` schedules component for repainting but this action has yet to be executed and it has to be executed on UI thread.

Basically each UI application has a separate, dedicated thread which calculates how things should be redrawn, and then redraws them.

Your `run` action is called by that thread and so `while(true)` is also being executed by this thread. Meaning, it never leaves `run` and never reaches the piece of code responsible for repainting.

The solution is to simply don't calculate any logic inside UI components:

- keep a separate thread (or thread pools) for computations, IO operations etc
- when you perform some action on the UI which would update the model, calculate  sth etc, dispatch it to a separate thread,
- once this thread is done it should call UI component, so that it would perform only logic necessary for this particular UI change

What you made is a common error, which you can read more about searching for phrases like "why not blocking on UI thread", "why separate UI thread", etc. It is responsible for issues like UI being unresponsive (you click something and then everything freezes for a moment) and in cases like `while(true)` it blocks UI indefinitely. I am afraid that using multiple threads is the only recommended way until JVM introduce some other native way of having continuations.

Comment: Ok, thanks! now they are moving. They are flickering tho. But I think this issue has been addressed in another post.

Comment: Just a while guess but I think flickering might be due to too fast repaint and/or no "double buffering" during drawing, but yeah, this is another topic.